# Como unir dos consultas Mysql en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente problema y espero explicarlo bien:

Tengo una primera consulta con varios LEFT JOIN donde muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta consulta funciona perfecta para mi por que tengo los codigos bien organizados e irrepetibles, es decir, si hago una búsqueda por pro_codigo en esa consulta, no habrá ningún código repetido.

El problema surge cuando quiero hacer un LEFT JOIN con la tabla transito.
La tabla transito tiene la siguiente estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y tiene una relación de uno a muchos, es decir, un pro_codigo puede tener varios tra_cantidad, tra_fecha, pue_id, lo que quiere decir que si hago una busqueda por un pro_codigo en especifico, pueden salir varios registros:

[image: introducir la descripción de djdaimagen aquí]

Esto es una búsqueda en la tabla transito con el pro_codigo: ADV5011226

Como podrán imaginar lo que quiero hacer es no perder esa relación de la primera consulta, donde tengo los códigos irrepetibles y organizados pero incluyendo la información de la tabla transito, **ESTO POR QUE AL MOMENTO DE MOSTRARLOS REGISTROS EN HTML, NO ESTÉN REPETIDOS**.

La primera consulta donde no menciono a la tabla transito:

```
SELECT dpro.pro_codigo,dpro.numero_parte,dpro.pro_descripcion,dpro.en_pro_descripcion_delval, IFNULL(dscol.saldo,0) as saldo,IFNULL(ad.adu_prom_sum,0) as adu, 
    IFNULL(db.buf_cantidad,0) as buffer, cla_nombre, cla_color, cla_color_letra, 
    IFNULL(pn.prn_color,'#22222') as prn_color, IFNULL(pn.prn_color_letra,'black') as prn_color_letra 
    FROM delval_produc dpro 
    LEFT JOIN delval_saldos_col_actual dscol USING (pro_codigo) 
    LEFT JOIN adu_tabla ad USING (pro_codigo) 
    LEFT JOIN delval_buffer_colcol db USING (pro_codigo) 
    LEFT JOIN delval_clase_nacional dcn USING (pro_codigo) 
    LEFT JOIN clase c USING (cla_nombre) 
    LEFT JOIN perfil_nivel pn ON (CASE WHEN db.buf_cantidad IS NULL OR db.buf_cantidad=0 THEN NULL ELSE ROUND(COALESCE(dscol.saldo,0)/db.buf_cantidad*100,2) 
    BETWEEN prn_porc_ini AND prn_porc_fin END)
```

Y tengo esta otra consulta donde hago el LEFT JOIN con la tabla transito:

```
SELECT  dpro.pro_codigo,dpro.numero_parte,dpro.pro_descripcion,dpro.en_pro_descripcion_delval,
    IFNULL(dscol.saldo,0) as saldo,IFNULL(ad.adu_prom_sum,0) as adu, IFNULL(db.buf_cantidad,0) as buffer, 
    IFNULL(t.tra_cantidad,0)as tra_cantidad, IFNULL(t.tra_fecha,0) as tra_fecha, IFNULL(t.pue_id,0) as pue_id, 
    cla_nombre, cla_color, cla_color_letra, 
    IFNULL(pn.prn_color,'#22222') as prn_color, IFNULL(pn.prn_color_letra,'black') as prn_color_letra 
    FROM delval_produc dpro 
    LEFT JOIN delval_saldos_col_actual dscol USING (pro_codigo) 
    LEFT JOIN adu_tabla ad USING (pro_codigo) 
    LEFT JOIN delval_buffer_colcol db USING (pro_codigo) 
    LEFT JOIN transito t USING (pro_codigo)
    LEFT JOIN delval_clase_nacional dcn USING (pro_codigo) 
    LEFT JOIN clase c USING (cla_nombre) 
    LEFT JOIN perfil_nivel pn ON (CASE WHEN db.buf_cantidad IS NULL OR db.buf_cantidad=0 THEN NULL ELSE ROUND(COALESCE(dscol.saldo,0)/db.buf_cantidad*100,2) 
    BETWEEN prn_porc_ini AND prn_porc_fin END)
```

Esta ultima consulta tiene esto como OUTPUT:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me manda todos los registros con la informacion que quiero pero con los pro_codigos duplicados.

Esa misma consulta anterior le añadí un GROUP BY pro_codigo al final y funciona a medias, es decir si devuelve los codigos irrepetibles pero con solo el primer registro que encuentre en transito, los demás registros los omite y no los muestra!!

```
SELECT  dpro.pro_codigo,dpro.numero_parte,dpro.pro_descripcion,dpro.en_pro_descripcion_delval,
    IFNULL(dscol.saldo,0) as saldo,IFNULL(ad.adu_prom_sum,0) as adu, IFNULL(db.buf_cantidad,0) as buffer, 
    IFNULL(t.tra_cantidad,0)as tra_cantidad, IFNULL(t.tra_fecha,0) as tra_fecha, IFNULL(t.pue_id,0) as pue_id, 
    cla_nombre, cla_color, cla_color_letra, 
    IFNULL(pn.prn_color,'#22222') as prn_color, IFNULL(pn.prn_color_letra,'black') as prn_color_letra 
    FROM delval_produc dpro 
    LEFT JOIN delval_saldos_col_actual dscol USING (pro_codigo) 
    LEFT JOIN adu_tabla ad USING (pro_codigo) 
    LEFT JOIN delval_buffer_colcol db USING (pro_codigo) 
    LEFT JOIN transito t USING (pro_codigo)
    LEFT JOIN delval_clase_nacional dcn USING (pro_codigo) 
    LEFT JOIN clase c USING (cla_nombre) 
    LEFT JOIN perfil_nivel pn ON (CASE WHEN db.buf_cantidad IS NULL OR db.buf_cantidad=0 THEN NULL ELSE ROUND(COALESCE(dscol.saldo,0)/db.buf_cantidad*100,2) 
    BETWEEN prn_porc_ini AND prn_porc_fin END)
    GROUP BY pro_codigo
```

Había pensado tomar la primera consulta y unirla de alguna forma en PHP con SELECT * FROM transito, pero aquí si estoy un poco perdido...

**EL FIN DE TODO ESTO ES MOSTRAR EN UNA TABLA HTML Y PHP TODOS LOS CODIGOS IRREPETIBLES Y HACER OPERACIONES CON LOS CAMPOS DE TRA_CANTIDAD, TRA_FECHA Y PUE_ID...**

Alguna solución??

Comment: ¿Que información de la tabla `transito` quieres mostrar?¿y como quisieras mostrarla? Por ejemplo el `pro_codigo` del ejemplo tiene tres registros en la tabla `transito` como quisieras mostrar esas tres `tra_fecha` o `tra_cantidad` ¿mostrarias solo una?¿cual? o ¿quisieras ver todas pero en una misma columna separadas por coma?. Creo que ayudaría que agregues una tabla con el resultado deseado, a partir de un conjunto mínimo de datos de prueba.

Comment: Realmente no quiero mostrar ninguna info de esa tabla, como mencioné necesito estos campos para hacer operaciones, es decir, tengo una condición que dice si la fecha del día de hoy (23/09/2021) es igual a `tra_fecha` tome el valor de `tra_cantidad` y lo sume con otro valor que tengo en una operación en php. pero todo esto tiene que estar ligado a el pro_codigo

Comment: Entonces por ahí te conviene hacer otra query, que te traiga solo los `pro_codigo` y `tra_cantidad` de aquellas fechas que coinciden con la fecha actual, y utilizar dicha información para hacer los cálculos que necesitas. Si no hay fechas repetidas en `transito` para un mismo `pro_codigo`, puedes hacer un `LEFT JOIN` con esta query y ya no te duplicará los registros.

Comment: Estoy intentando hacer el query, me ayudas?  tengo una tabla que almacena la fecha actual `SELECT  dpro.pro_codigo,IFNULL(t.tra_cantidad,0)as tra_cantidad, IFNULL(t.tra_fecha,0) as tra_fecha, IFNULL(t.pue_id,0) as pue_id
        FROM delval_produc dpro 
        LEFT JOIN transito t USING (pro_codigo)
        LEFT JOIN vw_fecha_actual vw USING (vw.fecha_actual)
        WHERE t.tra_fecha = vw.fecha_actual`

Comment: Ahí publiqué una respuesta, tu query está bien, solo que para obtener la fecha actual utilizaría la función `CURDATE()`.

Comment: No necesitas vincular con `delval_produc`, ya que la columna `pro_codigo` también está en la tabla `transito`.

Answer (score 0):

En MySql la función `CURDATE()` te retorna la fecha actual.

A la fecha no le podría 0 is es nula, la dejaría nula.

```
SELECT  
      t.pro_codigo,
      IFNULL(t.tra_cantidad, 0) AS tra_cantidad, 
      t.tra_fecha,
      IFNULL(t.pue_id, 0) as pue_id         
FROM transito t               ​
WHERE t.tra_fecha = CURDATE();
```

Luego en tu query principal podrías hacer un `LEFT JOIN` con esta query (si en `transito` no puede haber fechas repetidas para un mismo `pro_codigo`, entonces al vincular con tu query principal ya no duplicará los `pro_codigo`).

En ese caso podrías usar esta query:

```
SELECT  
      pro_codigo,
      SUM(tra_cantidad) AS tra_cantidad, 
FROM transito            
WHERE tra_fecha = CURDATE()
GROUP BY pro_codigo;
```

En tu query principal, en lugar de vincular con `transito`, podrías vincular con esta query y ya no duplicará los registros.

Comment: funciona bien, pero si puede haber codigos con fechas repetidas, en ese caso que sucedería?

Comment: En el caso de que para un `pro_codigo` haya dos reigstros en `transito` con la fecha actual, ¿como haces la suma? ¿sumas ambos `tra_cantidad`?

Comment: Exactamente, si hay una fecha con dos tra_cantidad hace un SUM

Comment: En esa caso podrías vincular con la query que agregué en mi respuesta, y ya no duplicaría los registros porque habría una sola fila por `pro_codigo`.